# apk download from various websites

Tags: android

I am trying to download some apks online. Many download links have zipped folders. I unzipped it but there is no apk file in that. Is there any other way to get apk from thses zipped folders.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question.

Comment: It's OK, if you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download you linked works absolutely fine.

An APK is a package of files. It works the same kind of way as a zip folder.

Inside an APK you get "META-INF" and "res" folders as you have already found.

What you are doing, is infact opening the apk in your zip program.

**AKA The "ZIP" folder is the APK!!!**

Check the file extension and you will see it is `.apk`

[image]

To install it on your phone. There are many ways. One way is to transfer the file to your phone, and using a file browser on your phone, run the apk. (Note, you will need to allow 3rd party apk installs via settings)

Comment: Thanks. How do I use a ZIP folder as apk ? I thought APK is a file with .apk extension

Comment: @user200658. It is an apk extension. Check the download properly. Transfer it to your phone, then run it via your phone. Or what ever else you want to do with it.

Comment: Oh, I can not see that .apk.  Did you download it on phone ? I have to download it on desktop and then send it to Tablet. We have lock down tablets. Please send some more info.

Comment: @user200658 that is downloaded on my PC. via Google chrome. (and a screenshot of Google chrome download bar). Just trust the file is an apk, and copy it to your phone. And see if it works. Google, how to display file extensions on your PC. there will plenty of guids for your OS.

Comment: You are a genius!!!! I was using IE and it did not work. It's working via chrome. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You may have got the entire source code in the zipped folder.Unzip it and you will find a "bin" folder within it.Go into "bin" and there you will find your apk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no bin folder, only "META-INF" and "res" folders.

Comment: Check this: http://www.papktop.com/unit-converter-2-6-17.html  It has a link for Download from apktop